# docker-compose service version error

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run [this example](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/) from the official docker page.

However I am getting the following error:

> ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml' service 'version' doesn't have any configuration options. All top level keys in your docker-compose.yml must map to a dictionary of configuration options.

when running the following command:

`$ docker-compose run web django-admin.py startproject composeexample .`

I am using:

`$ docker-compose -version`

`docker-compose version 1.5.2, build 7240ff3`

on Ubuntu 16.04

Could not find any helpful posts / suggestions by googling the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `docker-compose` is too old.  The example you referenced uses the new "version 2" compose file format, which is only supported in recent (definitely 1.7.x, maybe 1.6.x?) versions of `docker-compose`.

The example compose file in step 9 of that example would look like this with your version of `docker-compose`:

```
db:
  image: postgres
web:
  build: .
  command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
  volumes:
    - .:/code
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
  depends_on:
    - db
```

Comment: Thx but after copying-pasting ur suggestion in my `docker-compose.yml` I am getting the following error: `ERROR: Validation failed in file './docker-compose.yml', reason(s):
Unsupported config option for 'web' service: 'depends_on'`

Comment: Okay, so `depends_on` is also too new.  Try this instead...or just upgrade your `docker-compose` so that all the docs and examples on the docker website will be useful to use as-is.

Comment: Ok it was a version issue...I ended up updating to 1.7.0. Thanks